# How to get the size of a file in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, command-line

So I'm tasked with writing a command line app that tells you the file size of a given directory. I'm basically going to replicate what the command `dir /s <dir>` does, but output the result to a text file to make it available for parsing later on.

Using VB.NET, I'm at a place where I need to get the size of a directory, but it seems there's no such ready-made property in the `DirectoryInfo` class. How do I get the size of a directory?

**EDIT:** If there's a built-in command or switch that can be typed into command line to automatically output the results of an operation to a .txt file then that would make this infinitely easier.

Comment: Check this link http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/d55216d6-1dfc-4b34-a57f-5f1be2c0ee4f/

Comment: As Damien says you need `.Length`. I believe to get a directory size you will need to iterate through the files within and total their `Lengths`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FileInfo doesn't have a [Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx) property in your version?

(Admittedly, DirectoryInfo doesn't have such a property - you'd need to define your own recursive function that explores the subdirectories and subfolders, based on a DirectoryInfo object, and returns the sum of their sizes)

---

Also, for most commands, you can send the output to a text file using the `>` operator, e.g.:

```
dir >myoutput.txt /s <dir>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would just the CMD command below

```
dir >dirinfo.txt
```

Just replace the file name with whatever name and path you need. This will export the results to the test file.